# Trig question: angle of elevation and height of cliff

Tags: trigonometry

From a point $P$, a person observes that the angle of elevation of the top of a cliff $A$ is $40°$. After walking $100$ m towards $A$ along a straight road inclined upwards at an angle of $15°$ to the horizontal, the angle of elevation of $A$ is observed to be $50°$. Find the vertical height of $A$ above $P$.

I really need help with this question. I keep getting $219.8$m when the answers say $212.3$m. There is no working out in the solutions.

The diagram i used can be accessed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Su59ZXg_QfAc_p8xceDBw5da0kKqeetn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Would you please explain how did you get this answer?

Comment: would the diagram I drew help?

Comment: I guess it would help.

Comment: diagram is linked in the orginal post

Comment: From the text it seems that the $100$ m walk was uphill so I would understand it as your $x_1$ is the $100$ m

Comment: I get the correct answer using my approach. Do you?

Comment: Oh ok makes sense, so the 100 metres isn’t referring to the horizontal distance travelled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in your diagram. In your diagram, you are supposed to mark $x_1$ as $100$m and not the base in the right triangle that also has side $y$ opposite angle $15^{\circ}$. Using this correction and your diagram the vertical height ($h$) should be (in meters):
$$h=100\left(\sin 15^{\circ} + \frac{\sin 25^{\circ} \sin 50 ^{\circ}}{\sin 10^{\circ}}\right) \approx 212.3$$